# How to read a pdf file stored in sdcard using adobe reader installed in the android device?

Tags: android, pdf

*i new to android application developemnt. I am trying to open the pdf file stored in sd card.I used this code snippet but this opens the viewer in the device but not the file given in the path. Any help appreciated.*

```
    Intent intent = new  Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+/sample.pdf"));
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intent.setPackage("com.adobe.reader"); selects the adobe reader directly 
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent,0);
    if (activities.size() >= 0) 
            {
    startActivity(intent);


    } else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "No Application Available to View PDF",

        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read pdf file from sdcard by giving the path and try the following.

```
File pdfFile = new File(path); 
if(pdfFile.exists()) 
{

    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile); 
    Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
    pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    try
    {
        startActivity(pdfIntent);
    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(uractivity.this, resource.getString(R.string.noapplicationpdf), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Than you this helped me. I was not giving the path name correct.

Comment: you can give the path to find pdf files as below.                   String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/your_folder".

Comment: I have adobe acrobat on my phone but it doesn't open pdf file

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(filename);
intent.setDataAndType( Uri.fromFile( file ), "application/pdf" );
startActivity(intent);
```

or

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setPackage("com.adobe.reader");
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);
```