# Unable to open pdf client on button click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file

Here is my button click code:

```
    private View.OnClickListener onButton1=new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v){
        copyAssets();

        File rootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(rootDir + "/sdcard/" +"save.pdf");
         if(file.exists())
           {
            // do action here

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromFile(file));
            intent.setType("application/pdf");

            startActivity(intent);
           }
         else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File does not exist",         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

       }
     };
```

copyAssets() is a function by which I copy the file from my assets folder to my SD-Card and it is working as I checked on my device, but I am unable to open it when I click the button. My file is named as save.pdf on the SD-Card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read pdf file from SDCard by giving the path as follows:

```
        File pdfFile = new File(path); 
        if(pdfFile.exists()) 
        {

            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile); 
            Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            try
            {
                startActivity(pdfIntent);
            }
            catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(uractivity.this, "File does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where do I specify the file name?

Comment: in the path variable, path = rootDir + "/sdcard/" +"save.pdf";

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747693/how-to-read-a-pdf-file-stored-in-sdcard-using-adobe-reader-installed-in-the-andr